# Does SSL affect the way a website works?

Tags: ssl, integration

I will soon have to activate a SSL certificate on my website and I'd like to know if that will affect the way the website works.

Things like setting cookies,sessions, ajax requests, file uploads, etc, will work the same? Or will need any code modification?

I basically need it enabled in one form in the user private area where I ask for payment information, should I activate it only there? Or on all the pages of the private area?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: You will need to ensure every request on the page is prefixed with https:// and not http:// otherwise the certificate will show as a warning that the page contains both secure and insecure information

Comment: @NicholasKing Or better still omit the protocol and hostname altogether, just use host-relative URLs, then the pages will work either way.

Comment: @EJP That's best practice and will transmit over https:// by default, but you need to be careful of other things like jquery for example if you are pulling it down from google or a CDN then the call to the CDN needs to be amended from http:// to https://